# How to update TypeScript in Ubuntu

Tags: typescript, ubuntu-14.04, npm-install

How can I update typescript 1.8.0 to TypeScript typescript@^2.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04 machine? I am using `npm install -g typescript@next` command but it doesn't update to the latest version.

I tried using this command:

```
npm install -g typescript@rc
```

Console Output

> /usr/bin/tsc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
>   /usr/bin/tsserver -> /usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
>   /usr/lib
>   `-- typescript@2.0.2

When I try to run command `which tsc`, I get back the following output :

> /usr/local/bin/tsc

Comment: `npm install -g typescript@next` should install the 2.1 nightly; `npm install -g typescript@rc` should install the 2.0.2 RC.

Comment: @cartant thnx for response, I tried 2nd one, it's showing installed but when I m using **tsc -v** for showing version, it's still showing 1.8.0 only.

Comment: Include in your question the console output from the `npm install -g typescript@rc` command and the output from the `which tsc` command.

Comment: It's a path-related problem. It's installed fine, but there is another `tsc` that is being found first. Someone more familiar with Ubuntu should be able to help you out from here.

Comment: Why do you want `tsc` installed globally? It should be a dependency of your project and then called through `npm` scripts.